# How to disable asp.net radiobuttonlist via jQuery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, radiobuttonlist

I have a checkbox and radiobuttonlist defined as follows:

```
<asp:CheckBox id="chkChange" runat="server" text="Enable" />
<br />
<asp:RadioButtonList id="rblConsole" runat="server" cssclass="console">
    <asp:ListItem text="XBox 360" value="xbox" />
    <asp:ListItem text="Playstation 3" value="playstation" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

These controls are in a content page with a master page so the actual html rendered is:

```
<table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblConsole" class="console" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblConsole_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblConsole" value="xbox" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblConsole_0">XBox 360</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblConsole_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rblConsole" value="playstation" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rblConsole_1">Playstation 3</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On the javascript onclick on the checkbox I want to disable the radio buttons in the rblConsole radiobutton list.

I'm trying to get at the radio buttons via the jQuery endswith selector:

```
function ToggleEnabled() {
        var isChecked = $("*[id$='chkChange']").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked) {
            $("*[name$='rblConsole'").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("*[name$='rblConsole'").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
```

So, how to disable these via jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the closing square bracket in the selector.  It should be:

```
$("*[name$='rblConsole']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Doh!  My bad.

Answer (score 3):

first, remove the apostrophy in the attribute selector

```
function ToggleEnabled() {
        var isChecked = $("*[id$='chkChange']").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked) {
            $("*[name$=rblConsole").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("*[name$=rblConsole").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
```

second, it is better tu use the ClientID property of the controls to get the elements ids:

```
function ToggleEnabled() {
        var isChecked = $("#<%=chkChange.ClientID %>").is(":checked");
        if (isChecked) {
            $("#<%=rblConsole.ClientID %>").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $("#<%=rblConsole.ClientID %>").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The second way of doing this did not work. There is a table created with this ID, but the radio buttons themselves have an appended number (e.g. _0, _1). Correct way should be $("input[id^='<%= rblConsole.ClientID %>']").removeAttr("disabled"); where the id starts with (^) the client ID.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me,

For Disable

```
$("table[id$=<%= rblConsole.ClientID %>] input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

For Enable

```
$("table[id$=<%= rblConsole.ClientID %>] input").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check this:

```
$("input[type=radio][value=EIN]").prop("disabled", true);
```